# XQuery chaining XSLT transformations

Tags: xslt, xquery, exist-db

I am trying to transform an XML document through a series of XSL stylesheets transformations in eXist. I want to up-convert it from `pubs2` to `pubs9`. (I need to chain the result document of one transformation into the next transformation) I have tried several different ways and I was thinking it would be something like:

```
let $trans1 := for $a in $stylesheet/version[@pub = '3'] return transform:transform(doc("/db/myXML.xml"), $a, ())

let $trans2 := for $b in $stylesheet/version[@pub = '4'] return transform:transform(doc($trans1), $b, ())
```

etc

```
let $trans9 := for $z in $stylesheet/version[@pub = '9'] return transform:transform(doc($trans8), $z, ())
return $trans9
```

But I keep getting cardinality error. Is there a different way to do it?

BTW: I am using XQuery 1.0. I hope to convert to 3.0 very soon. :)

Comment: $trans1 is a sequence of nodes, so you cannot then use than in `fn:doc`, this is one the cardinality errors you will be seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion to apply a sequence of XSLTs to a source document, chaining the output of the first to the input of the second and so on. I have written the function `local:transform-pipeline` below which is a general purpose function that shows how this works.

```
xquery version "1.0";

import module namespace transform = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform";

declare function local:transform-pipeline($src as document-node()+, $transforms as xs:anyURI*, $params as node()?) as document-node()+ {
    if(empty($transforms))then
        $src
    else
        let $results := 
            for $s in $src
            return
                for $result in transform:transform($s, doc($transforms[1]), $params)
                return
                    document { $result }
        return            
            local:transform-pipeline($results, subsequence($transforms, 2), $params)
};


let $xslts := (xs:anyURI("/db/1.xslt"), xs:anyURI("/db/2.xslt"), xs:anyURI("/db/n.xslt"))
return
    local:transform-pipeline(doc("/db/my-document.xml"), $xslts, ())
```

Comment: Should this code Work with eXist 4.4.0? I adapted it, but I keep getting a "Unable to set up transformer [...] Content is not allowed in prolog" Error for a transformation that works fine when I call it via `transform:transform`

Comment: Got it working by changing the first line of the function declaration:
`declare function local:transform-pipeline($src, $transforms) as document-node()+ {`